# Gnuplot plotting of size polydisperse data file

Tags: gnuplot, plot

I have a lammps polydisperse in size datafile format as below:

```
## Atom-ID, x, y, eps, sigma
```

I am unable to visualize it in gnuplot. Can someone help me with details of the gnuplot command?

Comment: How about an [MCVE](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE) or at least some test data?

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you have installed gnuplot correctly. If that is so, then the question maybe is off-topic.

To plot the datafile using the 1st column as the x-axis and the 2nd
column as the y-axis, you can use

`gnuplot > plot “file.dat” using 1:2`.

In general for m-th column as your x-axis and n-th column as the y-axis, use

`gnuplot > plot "file.dat" using m:n`

A quick guide can be found [here](http://personalpages.to.infn.it/~mignone/Algoritmi_Numerici/gnuplot.pdf).

Comment: my data file contains different values of sigma to which i want to display image of different size particles, i did ---- pl 'xyzConfig-sig2.1-Var20pc.dat' u 2:3:4:5 w p pt 7 lc palette.---.This give same size of all particles. How to display polydisperse image. I am unable to manipulate the pointsize command

Comment: @JacksonKh It would be great if you could **edit** your question, with the command you mentioned above and also provide a screenshot of the output. Also, provide a few sample rows from the `xyzConfig-sig2.1-Var20pc.dat` file.